# The \symcal command doesn't work

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I am using Arial fonts with lualatex as my engine. The `\symcal` command doesn't work.
Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{xfakebold}
\RequirePackage{firamath-otf}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\setminus}]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\setminus,\boxast,\vardiamondsuit}]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
    \(\symcal{A}\)
    \(\mathcal{A}\)
\end{document}
```

I get the following output.
[image]
What could be the problem?

*Edit*: This works fine if use KpMaths fonts.  Is there no solution to make this work with firamath?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{xfakebold}
\RequirePackage[nosf,notext]{kpfonts-otf}
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\setminus}]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\setminus,\boxast,\vardiamondsuit}]
%\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
%\newfontface\normalsize{Arial}[Scale=1.2]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
    This is a test.
    \(\symcal{A}\)
    \(\symcal{C}\)

\end{document}
```

Looks like these symbols are missing in Firamath.

Comment: Arial does not have the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols (996 glyphs) Unicode block. The script/calligraphic math alphabet is in the MAS block. You will need to choose a suitable font: Cambria Math, etc.

Comment: FiraMath only has 16 of the many math alphabets in the MAS. The script alphabet is not one of them.

Comment: `\symcal{A}` will print  (U+1D49C MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL A) if the font has it. You need to find a font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `albatross` command/utility to find fonts on your system that have the glyphs you need.

On my system:

[image: math script]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\textmis{ℬℰ ℯ}

\newcommand\showsample[1]{%
\color{blue}#1 & \newfontfamily{\myfont}{#1}\myfont\textmis \\ %
}

\begin{document}

MAS: Mathematical Script alphabet random sample (text mode)

Do \texttt{albatross -b 3 U+1D49C} for a list of fonts.

---

\rowcolors{1}{blue!15}{blue!5}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\showsample{Asana Math}
\showsample{Cambria}
\showsample{Cambria Math}
\showsample{Catrinity}
\showsample{Code2003}
\showsample{Concrete Math}
\showsample{DejaVu Math TeX Gyre}
\showsample{Erewhon Math}
\showsample{FreeSerif}
%\showsample{Garamond\-Math}
\showsample{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\showsample{KpMath}
\showsample{Latin Modern Math}
\showsample{Libertinus Math}
\showsample{NewComputerModernMath}
\showsample{Noto Sans Math}
\showsample{Quivira}
\showsample{Segoe UI Symbol}
\showsample{STIX}
\showsample{STIX Math}
\showsample{STIX Two Math}
\showsample{Symbola}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\showsample{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\showsample{XCharter Math}
\showsample{XITS Math}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```